# How can a system recognize if two strings have the same or similar meaning?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, text-classification

How can a system recognize if two strings have the same or similar meaning?

For example, consider the following two strings

1. Wikipedia provides good information.
2. Wikipedia is a good source of information.

What methods are available to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the intent of the sentence is not an easy task. To get you started on what to do, have a look on word vectors. You can also download pre-trained [word2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59591075/8568784) models. They help in getting similarity of words and reasoning with words. To get the intent of a sentence, you can use LSTM.

Fun fact most NLP algorithms strip away punctuation with is sufficient for most cases, but to give a counter example.

```
The defendant, who looked apologetic, was found guilty.
The defendant who looked apologetic was found guilty.
```

They mean different things and are difficult to catch the intent even with the best algorithms.

PS: For those wondering the difference, in the second sentence it seems like there were two defendants, and it was the one who looked apologetic who was found guilty while the other walked away free.